# Can't open Dgn file with CadWorkspaceFactory?

Tags: arcobjects, dgn

I am trying to open Dgn File to get data. But I got the error: **"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component ?"** when using OpenFromFile statement, please see my codes:

```
 Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
             "esriDataSourcesFile.CadWorkspaceFactory");
 System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
 IWorkspaceFactory factory = obj as IWorkspaceFactory;
 IFeatureWorkspace workspace = (IFeatureWorkspace )factory.OpenFromFile("C:\\DC7.dgn", 0); // Throw Exception
```

May you help me ?

Regards,
Tai

Comment: In my experience that error message is some sort of default message that comes up when it doesn't know what to say...

Comment: What format is the DGN? v7 might better than v8 for using in the way.

Comment: Hi everyone, I found out the reason, I should use the directory path (not file name) in the OpenFromFile method